# Row dragging with tree data

Tags: ag-grid

I've an ag-grid with tree data like this

```
+ Grp1
    - Item1
    - Item2
+ Grp2
    ...
```

and move the groups and items by row dragging. Does anybody know how to move "Item1" from "Grp1" to the "root" level of the tree?

```
- Item1
+ Grp1
    - Item2
+ Grp2
    ...
```

I have tried to drop the row onto a special column, but the onRowDragMove event gets only the node/row under the "pointer" (not the column). Dropping outside of the grid is not possible since onDragEnd is not working outside the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You should have one root for everything (even it could be virtual) but only like that, you would be able to drag&drop to it.

```
Root <-- this could be virtual (just add the same 0-index item on each getDataPath array)
  Group 1
     Item 1
     Item 2
  Group 2
     Item 1
     Item 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a quite old topic, but since ag-grid did not have any improvisation with this and need to programmatically rewrite DnD function, thus some hack needs to be done.

Check the dragged node on whether it does exist in overNode( node that you will drag into ) as child node. If existed, assigned the overNode to its parent instead ( means that you will drag the node to overNode parent, for your case , it is the same level as Grp 1, Grp 2)

If the dragged node does not exist in overNode as its child, it will be moved into overNode as its child node instead.

```
if(folderToDropInto.allLeafChildren.length > 1 && folderToDropInto.allLeafChildren.includes(event.node)){
      folderToDropInto = overNode.parent
}
```